# How to use GPU in Google Colab?

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

Where can I do the configuration to make the training run using Google Colab GPU? Google Colab keep prompting me that I am not using the GPU run time and ask me to switch to a normal GPU run time. Any help would be appreciated thank you.